# How to solve this problem with CLLocationDegrees?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

I'm trying to open different locations depending on the number of the cell in a table view ,so I've written this function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

              let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = self.latitudes[indexPath.row]
               let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = self.longitude[indexPath.row]
              let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudes,longitude)
              let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
              mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
    }
```

But, Xcode is giving me this error "Cannot convert value of type '[CLLocationDegrees]' (aka 'Array') to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')"

Dous anyone know what should I do ?

Comment: You're passing `latitudes` instead of `latitude` as the first argument to `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake`

Comment: maybe your latitudes are an array of latitude?

Comment: Yes,they are both arrays and I've specified which item to get from the array

Comment: dan spotted your error, you are making the coordinate with (latitudes,longitude) instead if (latitude,longitude)